# How to update a list from from another WPF window

Tags: vb.net

I have two WPF windows each with their own class `mainwindow` and `settingswindow`. What I am looking to do is be able to edit the settings in the `settingswindow` and when you click apply or okay buttons have it update the `mainwindow` accordingly. When I click apply in the settings window it exports values to xml and save it in user application settings. So when I click apply I could just run the `mainwindow_load` sub in the `mainwindow` class to reload the data but I am not sure how to reference it or call it. I tried creating a new instance of the `mainwindow` class in the `settingswindow` class with

`Dim MainWindow As MainWindow = New MainWindow()`

which that didn't seem to work, but I don't think I want a new instance of `mainwindow` ?

I also tried making the sub `public shared` but I would need to adjust a lot of things to get it to work. Is that the correct approach ? Or is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new instance of mainwindow I really wanted to hit the already existing instance with
`Dim MainWindow As MainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow()` which allowed me to update the window in real time.

Answer (score 0):

The settings class has events such as PropertyChanged.  Implement code in settings.vb that resets the values in MainWindow:

```
MainWindow.mytextbox.text = settings.property("some property")
```

Comment: Though this answer didn't by itself really help much it did get me to look at it differently and ask the question differently. I did finally stumble across the answer and have it working as intended now. Thanks!